# Specify library path in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ide

How do I specify the library path, i.e., where to look up static/shared libraries in Visual Studio Code (C++)?

I've already specified the include path (header files) as follows:

```
   "includePath": [
        "${workspaceRoot}",
        "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6",
        "/usr/include/c++/6",
        "/usr/local/include",
        "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
        "/usr/include"
    ]
```

I've been searching for a JSON property called "libraryPath", but cannot find any.

Comment: Do you mean additiaonal library path?  For example; to include a **.lib file** in **$(ProjectDir)\3rdParty\WpdPack\Lib\x64** folder 
    
 `<AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(ProjectDir)\3rdParty\WpdPack\Lib\x64;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>`

Comment: Does you comment apply to Visual Studio Code? If so, where should I put this?

Comment: Actually , these settings are configured from **Visual Studio->Project Properties in graphical interface** , I have written the content of **.vcxproj** that is modified automatically

Comment: I'm not asking about Visual Studio, but Visual Studio Code!

Comment: Did find a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

The vscode requires a include path to highlight or resolve c++ symbols, but it doesn't need to know where lib is stored.

I wonder if you have any trouble at compile time？ In that case, you need to set up your compilation system (such as CMake). :)